# javax.json: Build a JSONArray from a List<Integer> and add it to a JSONObject

Tags: java, json

Simple task but I couldn't find a way to do it.

My output JSON needs to be

```
{
   "id" : "somestring", 
   "nums" : [44,31,87,11,34]
}
```

I'm using the `javax.json` library with `JSONObject` / `JsonArray`. There is a `List<Integer>` which comes in with the values for the 2nd field. These aren't objects, these are plain numbers. I don't know how to get a JSONValue from an Integer.

```
        Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        JsonBuilderFactory factory = Json.createBuilderFactory(config);
        JsonArray jsonArray = (JsonArray) Json.createArrayBuilder();
        for (Integer num: nums) // Assume a List<Integer> nums
            jsonArray.add(..); // What to do here? JSONValue from an Integer?
                               // Can't do jsonArray.add(num)

        // Final Object
        JsonObject value = factory.createObjectBuilder()
            .add("id", id)
            .add("nums", jsonArray); // Link up jsonArray to the 2nd Add
```

Note - can't add an Integer directly,
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**FINAL SOLUTION** (thanks [Deadpool](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56105177/1005607))

```
        Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        JsonBuilderFactory factory = Json.createBuilderFactory(config);
        JsonArrayBuilder jsonArrayBuilder = Json.createArrayBuilder();
        for (Integer num: nums) 
            jsonArrayBuilder.add(temp); // Note: adding to the Array Builder here

        // Now add to the final object
        JsonObject obj = factory.createObjectBuilder()
            .add("id", id)
            .add("nums", jsonArrayBuilder)  /* Note the Array Builder is passed in */
            .build();

        // The full object is complete now and can be printed
        // It looks like: { "id":"string", "nums":[4,6,1,2] }
        System.out.println("Object: \n" + obj.toString());
```

Answer (score 2):

`createArrayBuilder` method will return `JsonArrayBuilder` object, you should not do the explicit type casting. So first create array builder and then add `Integers` to it

```
JsonArrayBuilder jsonArray = Json.createArrayBuilder();
    for (Integer num: nums) {
        jsonArray.add(num); 
      }
```

Then finally call `build` method that will build `JsonArray`

```
JsonArray array = jsonArray.build();
```

Comment: Thanks this worked. Actually I shouldn't do `JsonArray array = jsonArray.build()` at the end because the Builder itself needs to be referenced when building the final object. I'll post my final solution based on your answer, thanks.

Comment: (Posted now as a separate answer)

Answer (score 0):

I see in your code that you are already using in the loop the ***Integer*** class which is an object-type wrapper of primitive type ***int***. So the call ***jsonArray.add*** should work because num is an object and not a primitive type.

```
for (Integer num: nums) // Assume a List<Integer> nums
            jsonArray.add(num);
```

Comment: No, doesn't work -- see screenshot I attached to the original post.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try this code.

```
for(Integer num : nums)
   jsonArray.add(num.intValue());
```